# Why does FindClusters put closer points into different clusters?

Tags: bugs, cluster-analysis

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier and persisting through 12.0**

<sub>Bug isn't present in version 8.0.4</sub>

---

I am trying to do clustering and then obtained a plot as below:-

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 1.5}, {10, 1}, {11, 1.5}};
clts = FindClusters[pts, 2]
ListPlot[clts, PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]

As we can see, the 2 points at the left are closer to each other, but they are now put in separated clusters. Why does that happen?

If I reverse the x-y coordinate of the points, the situation is still the same (that means `FindClusters` is not taking priority for x-coordinates). I then tried `FindClusters[pts, 2, CriterionFunction -> "CalinskiHarabasz"]`, the 2 closer points are still in different clusters. Finally, when I tried `FindClusters[pts1, 2, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance]`, the problem is finally solved and the 2 closer points are in the same cluster.

So I am curious: if the default distance is not the "Euclidean distance", what would that be? Why would it put the closer points into different clusters?

Comment: Bizarre. `Trace[FindClusters[pts, 2], HoldPattern[DistanceFunction -> _]]` shows a lot of `DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance`, so `FindClusters` appears to be using `EuclideanDistance` as default.

Comment: Works for me: https://imgur.com/a/RyTK78l

Comment: In this case, `FindClusters` internally uses ``MachineLearning`PackageScope`AutomaticDistanceFunction[Automatic][{"Numerical", "Numerical"}]`` as its distance function, which evaluates to `EuclideanDistance`. Huh.

Comment: What OS and version of Mathematica are you using? The code doesn't seem to use `EuclideanDistance` on Mathematica versions 11.1.1 and 11.2.0 on Windows, and 11.3.0 on Linux.

Comment: Many thanks. I see. I am using 11.2 on Windows and that's the reason. I just tried to run `Trace[FindClusters[pts, 2], HoldPattern[DistanceFunction -> _]]`, and I got `{DistanceFunction->MachineLearning'file39ClusterClassify'PackagePrivate'a$_,DistanceFunction->MachineLearning'file39ClusterClassify'PackagePrivate'a$_}`, what does that mean?

Comment: I observe the same with version 11.3 on Windows 7 x64. Looks like a bug, worth reporting. Version 8.0.4 gives the expected result.

Comment: @HMC Just a bunch of internal symbols. Don't worry about them.

Answer (score 3):

When using `FindClusters` or `ClusterClassify` there is some preprocessing going on that might change your data. In this case, if you compute

```
 c = ClusterClassify[pts, 2]
```

anche check for `c[[1]]` you will see that the data gets standardized first. To prevent the function to do that it is enough to specify a `DistanceFunction`.

When doing it you get the expected answer:

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 1.5}, {10, 1}, {11, 1.5}};
clts = FindClusters[pts, 2, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance]

{{{1, 1}, {2, 1.5}}, {{10, 1}, {11, 1.5}}}
```

Comment: "there is some preprocessing going on that might change your data" - isn't it a bug? Preprocessing must not change the input data!