# How to make the clustering result of version 11.2 and 11.3 same?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, compatibility

I was doing clustering analysis in version 11.2, with codes like below, and then got 12 clusters as the output:

```
data0 = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[12]; RandomReal[1, {100, 3}]];
cts = FindClusters[data0, Automatic, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance];
Length@cts
```

When I used 11.3 to rerun the notebook, the result totally changed. The number of clusters is changed from 12 to 22. In a [previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175172/why-does-findclusters-put-closer-points-into-different-clusters), I noted that some default options of `FindClusters` in 11.2 and 11.3 are different. As such, what options can I add to the codes of either 11.2 or 11.3 to make their result same to each other?

Many thanks!